# Double integral in matlab with non-uniform grid

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, discrete-mathematics

I know how to perform the single integral using the [trapezoidal rule for non-uniform grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Non-uniform_grid). If my function is `f(x,y)`,  then single integral over `dx` in MATLAB would look like

`m1=(sum(diff(x,1,2).*(f(:,1:end-1)+f(:,2:end)),2))/2`

Now if I have the function `f(x,y,z)` how to perform the double integral over `dydz` using the trapezoidal rule of non-uniform grid in MATLAB ?

Please note its a non-uniform grid.

Comment: Think of Fubini: you integrate first on y (and obtain a function of (x,z)) then on z.

Comment: What is a non-uniform grid?

Comment: Its the case where the spacing between 2 points is not uniform.

Comment: Do you want your own implementation, or can you use a built in function?

Comment: @pragmatist1: Nothing specific as far as I understand the method.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: If you could give the pseudo code it will be useful like for the single integral case I am taking the difference in direction 2 and summing in 2 direction since I want to calculate the marginals of joint pdf. I want to do the same in 3 dimensional case so I am confused as to in which i direction I take the difference and in which direction I sum up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the built in function `trapz` in MATLAB you can accomplish just that. Here's an example:

```
>> x = -3:.1:3;
y = -5:.1:5;
z = -10:0.1:10;
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
F = X.^2 + Y.^2 + Z.^2;
I = trapz(y,trapz(x,F,2));
I = squeeze(I);
```

What I'm doing is creating a mesh grid of my data points represented by lowercase `x,y,z`, and evaluating the function, in this case `X^2+y^2+Z^2`. You would already have alternate data for this. Keep in mind you can always use `griddata` to re-grid your data uniformly.

I then use `trapz` twice to integrate the x and y dimension. `trapz` specifically specifically integrates only over the first matrix dimension that's not equal to 1, allowing me to do this (see documentation here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html).

Finally, I use squeeze on the data to remove all singleton dimensions and return a vector. If I plot the data along the remaining dimension I get:

```
>> plot(z,I);
```

Comparing to my original function, which if integrated analytically between `-3 <= x <= 3` and `-5 <= y <= 5` I obtain: `680 + 60 z^2`. The two are in agreement.
[image: plot]